# any ways to trigger an scroll event like clicking in between the scrollbar thumb and the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Scroll snap is amazing and after some experiment there is a specific doubt I have.

I found that although it works well for small viewports. When you have a large scrollable area and you are snapping the item on the start.
If you are at the end of the scroll width and the left most card is slightly out of view. Scrolling one card to the left (pressing the prev button) will ended up snapping to two cards away. This is ok and it is not an issue.

The funny thing happens is that if you press between the scrollbar thumb and left button it actually snaps to the start of the nearest card.

The question is if there is an easy way to call this native scroll event (the click between the thumb and the button)

here is an image to make it clear:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for anyone wondering the method name that is equivalent to that is scrollBy.

So in my case I need to do:

```
nextClickHandler() {
  const el = document.getElementById(myElId);
  el.scrollBy({
    top: 0,
    left: 1, //-1 if you want to go previous 
             //and it will snap to the element that is the closest to the edge.
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

instead of :

```
nextClickHandler() {
  const el = document.getElementById(myElId);
  el.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: el.scrollLeft+cardWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```